# I cannot find out why this code keeps skipping a loop

Tags: node.js, dictionary, for-loop

Some background on what is going on:

We are processing addresses into standardized forms, this is the code to take addresses scored by how many components found and then rescore them using a levenshtein algorithm across similar post codes

The scores are how many components were found in that address divided by the number missed, to return a ratio

The input data, scoreDict, is a dictionary containing arrays of arrays. The first set of arrays is the scores, so there are 12 arrays because there are 12 scores in this file (it adjusts by file). There are then however many addresses fit that score in their own separate arrays stored in that. Don't ask me why I'm doing it that way, my brain is dead

The code correctly goes through each score array and each one is properly filled with the unique elements that make it up. It is not short by any amount, nothing is duplicated, I have checked

When we hit the score that is -1 (this goes to any address where it doesn't fit in some rule so we can't use its post code to find components so no components are found) the loop specifically ONLY DOES EVERY OTHER ADDRESS IN THIS SCORE ARRAY

It doesn't do this to any other score array, I have checked

I have tried changing the number to something else like 99, same issue except one LESS address got rescored, and the rest stayed at the original failing score of 99

I am going insane, can anyone find where in this loop something may be going wrong to cause it to only do every other line. The index counter of line and sc come through in the correct order and do not skip over. I have checked

I am sorry this is not professional, I have been at this one loop for 5 hours

```
    Rescore: function Rescore(scoreDict) {
    let tempInc = 0;
    //Loop through all scores stored in scoreDict
    for (var line in scoreDict) {

        let addUpdate = "";
        //Loop through each line stored by score
        for (var sc in scoreDict[line.toString()]) {
            console.log(scoreDict[line.toString()].length);

            let possCodes = new Array();
            const curLine = scoreDict[line.toString()][sc];
            console.log(sc);
            const curScore = curLine[1].split(',')[curLine[1].split(',').length-1];
            switch (true) {
                case curScore == -1:
                    let postCode = (new RegExp('([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][A-Z0-9]?[ ]?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})', 'i')).exec(curLine[1].replace(/\\n/g, ','));
                    let areaCode;

                    //if (curLine.split(',')[curLine.split(',').length-2].includes("REFERENCE")) {
                        if ((postCode = (new RegExp('(([A-Z][A-Z]?[0-9][A-Z0-9]?(?=[ ]?[0-9][A-Z]{2}))|[0-9]{5})', 'i').exec(postCode))) !== null) {
                            for (const code in Object.keys(addProper)) {
                                leven.LoadWords(postCode[0], Object.keys(addProper)[code]);
                                if (leven.distance < 2) {
                                    //Weight will have adjustment algorithms based on other factors
                                    let weight = 1;

                                    //Add all codes that are close to the same to a temp array
                                    possCodes.push(postCode.input.replace(postCode[0], Object.keys(addProper)[code]).split(',')[0] + "(|W|)" + (leven.distance/weight));
                                }
                            }

                            let highScore = 0;
                            let candidates = new Array();
                            //Use the component script from cityprocess to rescore
                            for (var i=0;i<possCodes.length;i++) {
                                postValid.add([curLine[1].split(',').slice(0,curLine[1].split(',').length-2) + '(|S|)' + possCodes[i].split("(|W|)")[0]]);

                                if (postValid.addChunk[0].split('(|S|)')[postValid.addChunk[0].split('(|S|)').length-1] > highScore) {
                                    candidates = new Array();
                                    highScore = postValid.addChunk[0].split('(|S|)')[postValid.addChunk[0].split('(|S|)').length-1];
                                    candidates.push(postValid.addChunk[0]);
                                } else if (postValid.addChunk[0].split('(|S|)')[postValid.addChunk[0].split('(|S|)').length-1] == highScore) {
                                    candidates.push(postValid.addChunk[0]);
                                }
                            }
                            score.Rescore(curLine, sc, candidates[0]);
                        }
                    //} else if (curLine.split(',')[curLine.split(',').length-2].contains("AREA")) {
                    //    leven.LoadWords();
                    //}
                    break;
                case curScore > 0:
                    //console.log("That's a pretty good score mate");
                    break;
            }
            //console.log(line + ": " + scoreDict[line].length);
        }
    }

    console.log(tempInc)
    score.ScoreWrite(score.scoreDict);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was calling the loop on the array I was editing, so as each element got removed from the array (rescored and moved into a separate array) it got shorter by that element, resulting in an issue that when the first element was rescored and removed, and then we moved onto the second index which was now the third element, because everything shifted up by 1 index

I fixed it by having it simply enter an empty array for each removed element, so everything kept its index and the array kept its length, and then clear the empty values at a later time in the code